# Understanding when merge commits are created and the need to avoid loads of merge commits

Tags: git, github

I tried proving a quote from my textbook, but failed. The quote is as follows:

> By default, when performing git pull, a merge commit will be created
> if the history of the local branch has diverged from the remote one.

However when I open gitk, I don't see anything special happening when I do `git pull`. The following steps are my reproducible example.

1. initalize a git repo `git init test`
2. make a dummy repo on Github and connect `test` to that dummy repo
3. add a random file, commit, and push it.
4. Open gitk and notice that there's only one commit
5. initalize another git repo `git init test2` in a different directory
6. git remote add origin [DUMMY_REPO_LINK] (the dummy repo from step 2)
7. `git pull origin master`
8. Open gitk and you will notice nothing changed

The problem is at the last step. Why did nothing change despite the local branch being different from the remote one? in other words, I want to create a merge commit using git pull and I want to know what I am doing wrong. Secondly, why is it a bad thing to have too many merge commits?

Any explanation would be great.

Comment: A merge commit would only be created if your local branch has changes that are not present on the remote. And only then when your `git pull` strategy is `--no-rebase`

Comment: @Phil sorry there should be a step before step 6, which is `git remote add origin [DUMMY_REPO_LINK]` (the dummy repo from step 2). After that, you have to `git pull origin master`. That's what I mean.

Comment: Why do you think there should be a merge commit done when their is no divergence? Does [the example in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_description) not answer your question? You have no local _F_ or _G_ commits

Comment: IMHO, it would be easier to understand what's going on if you think about this in the context of the `merge` command rather than `pull`.  Pull, does a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`, and it's the `merge` command that, by default, creates the merge commit *if needed*. Creating additional repos so you can pull is just adding unnecessary noise to your tests. You can simulate everything you need for your learning with just two branches in a local repo, and no remotes are needed.